# Listview with Multitouch for alphabetic scrolling

Tags: android, listview

Hallo,

In Android, the Listview has a "fastScroll" feature. In combination with an alphabeticindexer, you can directly scroll to certain letter in your list. But i would like to implent, that you can do the same thing with a "two finger" scrolling:
When you touch the display with two finger, the Listview scolls directly to the according letter. When you now scroll with two fingers, you scroll alphabeticly in the Listview.

My HTC Desire has this feature in the contacts list, so it must be possible somehow :-)

I have already searched a lot, but didn't find anything, that helps me. Does anybody know of a sample program or can give me some help, how to do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Harald

Comment: In what part do you need help? Detecting multitouch or scrolling to the letter?

Comment: Hello Pedro, I nedd help in the principal architecture. I have a ListActivity with a Listview. Should the ListActivity implement the the OnTouchListener and i have to do the eventhandling in OnTouch somehow, or do i need a subclass of a Listview? The AbsListView class uses a FastScroller, perhaps I need an own Listview subclass with an customized FastScroller? I just don't know, where to start at all, cause I'm doing Android programming since 3 weeks...